# SQL Server: How to list all CLR functions/procedures/objects for assembly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqlclr

Question: In SQL Server 2005, how can I list all SQL CLR-functions/procedures that use assembly xy (e.g. MyFirstUdp) ?

For example a function that lists HelloWorld for query parameter MyFirstUdp

```
CREATE PROCEDURE HelloWorld
AS EXTERNAL NAME MyFirstUdp.[SQL_CLRdll.MySQLclass].HelloWorld
GO
```

after I ran

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY MyFirstUdp FROM 'C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\SQL_CLRdll\SQL_CLRdll\bin\Debug\SQL_CLRdll.dll
```

I can list all assemblies and all functions/procedures,
but I seem to be unable to associate the assembly to the functions/procedures...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Check out the `sys.assembly_modules` view:

```
select * from sys.assembly_modules
```

This should list all functions and the assemblies they're defined in. See the [Books Online help page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180052.aspx) about it.

> Returns one row for each function,
>   procedure or trigger that is defined
>   by a common language runtime (CLR)
>   assembly.

Comment: Just FYI: User-Defined Types (UDTs) are found in `sys.assembly_types` and not in `sys.assembly_modules`.

Answer (score 21):

I use the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT      so.name AS [ObjectName],
            so.[type],
            SCHEMA_NAME(so.[schema_id]) AS [SchemaName],
            asmbly.name AS [AssemblyName],
            asmbly.permission_set_desc,
            am.assembly_class, 
            am.assembly_method
FROM        sys.assembly_modules am
INNER JOIN  sys.assemblies asmbly
        ON  asmbly.assembly_id = am.assembly_id
        AND asmbly.is_user_defined = 1 -- if using SQL Server 2008 or newer
--      AND asmbly.name NOT LIKE 'Microsoft%' -- if using SQL Server 2005
INNER JOIN  sys.objects so
        ON  so.[object_id] = am.[object_id]
UNION ALL
SELECT      at.name AS [ObjectName],
            'UDT' AS [type],
            SCHEMA_NAME(at.[schema_id]) AS [SchemaName], 
            asmbly.name AS [AssemblyName],
            asmbly.permission_set_desc,
            at.assembly_class,
            NULL AS [assembly_method]
FROM        sys.assembly_types at
INNER JOIN  sys.assemblies asmbly
        ON  asmbly.assembly_id = at.assembly_id
        AND asmbly.is_user_defined = 1 -- if using SQL Server 2008 or newer
--      AND asmbly.name NOT LIKE 'Microsoft%' -- if using SQL Server 2005
ORDER BY    [AssemblyName], [type], [ObjectName]
```

Please note:

1. User-Defined Types (UDTs) are found in: `sys.assembly_types`
2. You can only list SQLCLR references that have been used in `CREATE { PROCEDURE | FUNCTION | AGGREGATE | TRIGGER | TYPE }`  statements. You cannot find SQLCLR methods that have not yet been referenced by a `CREATE`. Meaning, you cannot say: "give me a list of methods in this assembly that I can create T-SQL objects for".

For more info on working with SQLCLR in general, please visit: [SQLCLR Info](https://sqlclr.org/)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a generalization of srutzky's query (above) that goes through all DBs on a server using a cursor. Sorry about the formatting, but this is handy if you have to search through 500 DB's you've inherited.

```
set nocount on
declare @cmd nvarchar(4000)

declare curDBs cursor read_only for 
    SELECT name FROM MASTER.sys.sysdatabases
declare @NameDB nvarchar(100)

create table #tmpResults (
      DatabaseName nvarchar(128)
    , ObjectName nvarchar(128)
    , ObjectType char(2)
    , SchemaName nvarchar(128)
    , AssemblyName nvarchar(128)
    , PermissionSet nvarchar(60)                        
    , AssemblyClass nvarchar(128)
    , AssemblyMethod nvarchar(128));

open curDBs; while (1=1)
    begin
        fetch next from curDBs into @NameDB
        if @@fetch_status <> 0 break
        set @cmd = N'
            USE [' + @NameDB + N'];
            begin try
            insert into #tmpResults
                SELECT      ''' + @NameDB + N''',
                            so.name AS [ObjectName],
                            so.[type],
                            SCHEMA_NAME(so.[schema_id]) AS [SchemaName],
                            asy.name AS [AssemblyName],
                            asy.permission_set_desc,
                            am.assembly_class,  
                            am.assembly_method  
                    FROM sys.assembly_modules am
                        INNER JOIN  sys.assemblies asy
                            ON  asy.assembly_id = am.assembly_id
                                AND asy.is_user_defined = 1 
                        INNER JOIN  sys.objects so
                            ON  so.[object_id] = am.[object_id]
            UNION ALL
                SELECT      ''' + @NameDB + N''',
                            at.name AS [ObjectName],
                            ''UDT'' AS [type],
                            SCHEMA_NAME(at.[schema_id]) AS [SchemaName], 
                            asy.name AS [AssemblyName],
                            asy.permission_set_desc,
                            at.assembly_class,
                            NULL AS [assembly_method]
                    FROM  sys.assembly_types at
                        INNER JOIN  sys.assemblies asy
                            ON  asy.assembly_id = at.assembly_id
                                AND asy.is_user_defined = 1 
                    ORDER BY    [AssemblyName], [type], [ObjectName]
                print ''' + @NameDB + N'  ' +  cast(@@rowcount as nvarchar) + N'''
            end try
            begin catch
                print ''Error processing ' + @NameDB  + '''
            end catch
        '
        --print @cmd
        EXEC sp_executesql @cmd
    end
close curDBs; deallocate curDBs

select * from #tmpResults
drop table #tmpResults
```

Comment: Perfect. Just what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

Here it a script found on [sqlhint.com](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/tsql/list-all-clr-functions-and-procedures-associated-net-assembly):

```
SELECT
        SCHEMA_NAME(O.schema_id) AS [Schema], O.name,
        A.name AS assembly_name, AM.assembly_class, 
        AM.assembly_method,
        A.permission_set_desc,
        O.[type_desc]
FROM
        sys.assembly_modules AM
        INNER JOIN sys.assemblies A ON A.assembly_id = AM.assembly_id
        INNER JOIN sys.objects O ON O.object_id = AM.object_id
ORDER BY
        A.name, AM.assembly_class
```

Also, you have the option to see all the places where that [CLR object is used](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/tsql/clr-functions-and-procedures-usage).

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT 
      modules.assembly_class AS AssemblyClass,
      modules.assembly_method AS MethodName,
      obj.type_desc AS MethodType,
      files.name AS FilePath,
      assemb.name AS AssemblyName,
      assemb.clr_name,
      assemb.create_date,
      assemb.modify_date,
      assemb.permission_set_desc
      --,*
FROM   
     sys.assembly_modules AS modules
     JOIN sys.assembly_files AS files ON files.assembly_id = modules.assembly_id
     JOIN sys.assemblies AS assemb ON assemb.assembly_id = modules.assembly_id
     JOIN sys.objects AS obj ON obj.object_id = modules.object_id
```

Comment: First answer that includes the path to the actual assembly on disk!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_clr_appdomains;
```

which returns a list of assemblies and in what database they are stored.